# Should I check for nil in copyWithZone:?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic-memory-allocation, nscopying

In the Sketch example, in `-[<NSCopying> copyWithZone:]` is not checked if `-[<NSObject> init]` returns `nil`:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    SKTGraphic *copy = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    copy->_bounds = _bounds;
    copy->_isDrawingFill = _isDrawingFill;
    copy->_fillColor = [_fillColor copy];
    copy->_isDrawingStroke = _isDrawingStroke;
    copy->_strokeColor = [_strokeColor copy];
    copy->_strokeWidth = _strokeWidth;
    return copy;
}
```

This means that there will be a null dereference at runtime if it does return `nil` (i.e. a bug).

Is it usual that in `-[<NSCopying> copyWithZone:]` the program does not check if `-[<NSObject> init]` returns `nil`? Should I also do this not? I though of this:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    SKTGraphic *copy = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    if (copy) {
        copy->_bounds = _bounds;
        copy->_isDrawingFill = _isDrawingFill;
        copy->_fillColor = [_fillColor copy];
        copy->_isDrawingStroke = _isDrawingStroke;
        copy->_strokeColor = [_strokeColor copy];
        copy->_strokeWidth = _strokeWidth;
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to agree and say it should be checking for nil since the copy is accessing instant variables directly which will result in a crash if the copy is nil. If it were just accessing properties and methods that would not be an issue.